# Access named computer on domain without using IP address

Tags: windows, windows-sbs-2008, windows-xp

I added a computer to a Windows SBS 2008 domain, called it ps076.  When I try to access the D: drive of the computer through Windows Explorer (I have admin rights) using this syntax:

```
\\ps076\d$
```

I get an error message that says:

```
Windows cannot access \\ps076\d$

Check the spelling of the name.  Otherwise there might be a problem with your network. To
try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose.
```

I clicked diagnose and troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem.

When I enter it by the local IP address instead, I can gain access the drive after entering my admin credentials.

```
\\192.168.2.135\d$
```

The PS076 computer uses Windows XP professional.  Can someone help me understand why the computer name is not sufficient to locate this computer.  I have set up numerous other computers on our network and have always been able to access them by the computer name.

I want to be able to access this computer by the same name all the time as I will be writing some programs to grab data off the D: drive and it will simplify that process.

Comment: What's `nslookup PS076` tell you?

Comment: jscott - it says Server: ps001.xxxxx.local, Address: 192.168.2.121, Name: ps076.xxxxx.local, Address 192.168.2.135

Comment: Don't use Windows XP! Check the Firewall.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, it's a million dollar driveshaft balancer, we bought it 4 months ago and it came with XP.  It talks to a PLC and the vendor said we couldn't upgrade for various reasons.

Comment: can you map the filepath to a local drive? Does that work by name? By IP?

Comment: When i do it by name, i get access denied "The server's clock is not synchronized with the primary domain controller's clock".  I can map by IP.

Comment: Try making sure the times are synced with the DC on all the applicable machines. That may very well be the issue. When time is not synced to approx (~10-20 minutes -someone correct my numbers please) between machines; authentication/access will fail even if the user has the correct permissions.

Comment: RFC 4430 "If the server clock and the client clock are off by more than the policy-determined clock skew limit (usually 5 minutes), the server MUST return a KRB_AP_ERR_SKEW"  It's 5 minutes on Windows too.

Comment: BlueCompute and out-null, That was it!  The two clocks were off by about 7 minutes.  I ran NET TIME \\SERVER /SET /Y from PS076 and it fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will give you both time to write this in as an answer if you want the points, you guys figured it out, not me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clock on the Windows XP computer was out of sync with the domain controller clock, after running

```
NET TIME \\MyDomainControllerComputerName /SET /Y
```

from the command prompt on the Windows XP computer, I was able to locate the computer by name in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

This might be due to DNS name resolving issue. Try adding the following in the hosts file and check

```
File path :  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Attribute to add  : 192.168.2.135 ps076
```